# TinyMCE migration 5.7.1 to 6.5.1, Image source blob warning message not visible

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

While using 'Insert/Edit Image' option, provided source as `blob:https://www.google.com/`.
[blob source provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0fkA.png)

This don't show warning message for this blob input.
[No blob warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AeHF.png)

As in TinyMCE-5.7.1, it shows warning message if source provided as `blob:https://www.google.com/`.
[warning message for blob input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQycp.png)